# Android Manifest

Tags: android, xml

I found a code on internet for displaying a splash screen before starting an android application. He made some changes in the code which he didn't explain well.

- He used Launcher for Splash screen `Activity` and used Default in main android `Activity`.
- He used Package name with main class name instead of pre-generated code for android:name in action.
  Here is the code.

  ```
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity
      android:name=".StartingPoint"
      android:label="@string/title_activity_starting_point" >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.alfred.splashscreenwithsound.STARTINGPOINT" />

          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  ```

So my question

1. What is the difference between **LAUNCHER** & **DEFAULT**.
2. Is there any good behind changing the `android:name` in action to the package name.

Comment: The activity which you define as launcher, will be displayed as your app's first screen after clicking your app icon in the app menu of the phone.

Answer (score 1):

`"android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"` serves as our main entry into the app.

`android.intent.category.DEFAULT`  be set if the `Activity` should be an option for the default action (center press) to perform on a piece of data.

Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: lets say the first screen isn't splash screen, it provides a set of buttons which bring up another screen, so thefirst screen will always be launcher and every other screen after that will be default.

Comment: @Alfred : yes, just like that.

Answer (score 1):

when you write **LAUNCHER** it will launch application with Icon and if you remove it it will not show you the application Icon

Answer (score 0):

**LAUNCHER** is your main page **DEFAULT** is your `Activity` page when load the app. on device first **LAUNCHER** will open. Then If you trigger your activity page **DEFAULT** will open.